# Is it possible to get the raw process.argv input in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, argv

I need to forward the raw NodeJS process.argv to a child process. The problem I am running into is that process.argv is stripping quotes from original arguments.

Let's say I have the following executables on my machine:

- /some/random/path/bin/executable1;
- /some/random/path/bin/executable2;
- /some/random/path/bin/executable3;

I am using Node to create aliases for these.

- `alias.js executable1`
- `alias.js executable2`
- `alias.js executable3`

Now, let's suppose I execute `alias.js executable1 -c"this is my input"`. `process.argv` returns:

`[ '-cthis is my input']`

This makes it impossible for me to pass through arguments as they were originally inputted. Can the raw input be accessed via NodeJS?

Answer (score 2):

This is done by the shell before the input is handed to the application.  The quotes are used to prevent the shell from interpreting the spaces as indicating that the next string is a new param.

Depending on the shell you are using you may be able to escape quotes with \. However, in your example you need the quotes around your input to wrap your param as it contains spaces.  You could escape any quotes found within your string with a \ and just assume that the value given to the param is always wrapped in quotes and that would not be wrong.

Its hard to imagine a scenario where you need the quotes as they have already served their purpose of ensuring the whole value is passed in the correct param position.